# Ajax request validation in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, validation

Here it asks validation for first table only. I wanna validation for all three tables 
[image]I have a form which makes a ajax call to the controller based on selection of check boxes.

Ajax displays a table which is designed in controller with validation.

when I select three check boxes and hit the submit button, ajax retrieves me three tables. My problem is when click on submit button without filling table details it asks validation for first table only.

I want to show validation for all tables that ajax fetches.

my form is:

```
{!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'lawpopupformdata', 'files' => true)) !!}
    <div class="modal fade" id="lawpopupdata" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialoglaws">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Law(s)</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body modal-bodylaws">
                    <input type="hidden" name="company_id" value="{{$company_master->id}}">
                    @foreach ($laws as $law)
                        <?php
                        $sublaws = DB::table('tbl_law_sub_master')->where('lm_id', $law->id)->select('*')->get(); ?>
                        <ul style="list-style:none;">
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="law_type_id[]" id="law_type_id{{ $law->id }}" class="delclass" value="{{ $law->id }}" reldeltype="{{ $law->id }}" />
                                <strong>{{ $law->lm_id }} ( {{ $law->law_name }} )</strong>
                                <ul style="list-style:none;">
                                    @foreach ($sublaws as $sublaw)
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="law_sub_type_id[]" id="law_sub_type_id{{$sublaw->id}}" value="{{$sublaw->id}}" class="delsubclass" reldeltype="{{ $law->id }}" reldelsubtype="{{$sublaw->id}}" />
                                            {{ $sublaw->lms_id }} ( {{ $sublaw->sub_law_name }} )</li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    @endforeach </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn green">
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn red" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="btn blue">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    </form>
```

ajax code is:

```
$("#lawpopupformdata").submit(function(event){
            var data_id = $(this).data('id');
            var row_id=$("#row_id").val();
            var start_date = $("#company_start_date").val();
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ URL::to('admin/postlawsdata') }}" + '?start_date=' + start_date,
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (returndata) {
                    var res_sublaw_content=returndata.law_info;
                    var res_sublaw_content1=returndata.law_info;

                    var res_validate_laws = returndata.validate_laws;
                    var res_sub_law_count = returndata.sub_law_count;


                    if(res_sub_law_count==0)
                    {
                        bootbox.alert("Please Select Atleast One Law");
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById("sublaws_content").innerHTML = "";
                        $('#sublaws_content').append(res_sublaw_content);
                        $('#sublaws_content1').append(res_sublaw_content1);
                        $('#laws_data1').val(res_sub_law_count);
                        $('.locationparentsd').bind('change', function(event)
                        {
                            parent_loc_sd = $(this).val();
                            var loc_att_law_id = $(this).attr('att_law_id');
                            var loc_sd_name = '.dynamiclocationparentsd'+loc_att_law_id;
                            $(loc_sd_name).val(parent_loc_sd);
                        });

                        $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                            todayBtn: "linked",
                            autoclose: true,
                            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
                        });
                        $('#lawpopupdata').modal('hide');
                        $('#save').show();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

my controller function is:

```
 public function postlawsdata()
    {
        $lawdata=Input::get('law_type_id');
        $sublawdata=Input::get('law_sub_type_id');
        $start_date = Input::get('start_date');
//        $law_date=Input::get('company_start_date');
        $res_div='';
        $sub_law_count=count($sublawdata);
        $validate_laws='';
        if(count($sublawdata)>0)
        {

            for($i=0;$i<count($lawdata);$i++)
            {
                $law_details = DB::table('tbl_law_master')->where('id', $lawdata[$i])->select('tbl_law_master.id as law_id', 'tbl_law_master.lm_id', 'tbl_law_master.law_name')->first();

                $sublaw_details = DB::table('tbl_law_sub_master')
                    ->where('tbl_law_sub_master.lm_id', $lawdata[$i])
                    ->whereNull('tbl_law_sub_master.deleted_at')
                    ->select('tbl_law_sub_master.id as sublaw_id', 'tbl_law_sub_master.sub_law_name','tbl_law_sub_master.lms_id')->get();


                if(count($sublaw_details)>0)
                {
                    $res_div.='<table width="100%" border="0"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">';
                    $res_div.='<tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">    
                                        <strong>'.$law_details->lm_id.' ('.$law_details->law_name.')</strong>
                                    </td>
                                    <td >
                                        <span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span><input type="text" value="'.$start_date.'" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY (Start Date)" name="law_start_date[]" id="law_start_date" att_law_id="'.$lawdata[$i].'"  class="date-picker required locationformstyle locationparentsd dynamiclocationparentsd'.$lawdata[$i].'">
</td></tr><tr><td>
                                        <span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span><input type="text" placeholder="Law Registration No." name="law_reg_no" id="law_reg_no" class="locationformstyle required">

                                    </td>
                                    </tr>';

                    foreach($sublaw_details as $sublawdetails)
                    {
                        if (in_array($sublawdetails->sublaw_id, $sublawdata))
                        {
                            $res_div.='<tr>
            <td width="220">Start Date: <input type="text" name="sub_law_start_date[]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" onfocus="this.blur()" class="locationformstyle date-picker dynamiclocationparentsd'.$lawdata[$i].'" att_law_id="'.$lawdata[$i].'"> </td>
            <td width="220">End Date: <input type="text"  name="sub_law_end_date[]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" onfocus="this.blur()" class="locationformstyle date-picker"></td>
            <td align="left"><strong>'.$sublawdetails->lms_id.' ('.$sublawdetails->sub_law_name.')</strong>
            <input type="hidden" class="locationformstyle" name="company_sub_laws[]" value="'.$sublawdetails->sublaw_id.'">
            </td>
            </tr>
            ';
                        }
                    }
                    $res_div.='</table>';
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $validate_laws='Please Select Atleast One Law';
        }
        $data=array(
            'law_info'=>$res_div,
            'validate_laws'=>$validate_laws,
            'sub_law_count'=>$sub_law_count
        );
        return json_encode($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function postlawsdata()
```

change it to

```
 public function postlawsdata(Request $request)
```

and then add this

```
$this->validate($request,[
   //your validation
]);
```

Comment: where in controller should i write $this->validate($request,[ ]);

Comment: at the first line of the controller, right after you open the bracket